Can “digit” be used for numeral systems by any bases?
In the decimal numeric system, I often see like the following sentence:

The base-10 number 196210 has four digits.

Can I use “digit” for any bases? For example:

The base-2 number 10102 has four digits.


The base-16 number fe3716 has four digits.


It is a reasonable question to ask, but on this site it is expected that questioners will have consulted one or more dictionaries first, and ask here only if they cannot find a clear answer there.  “Digit.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digit. Accessed 13 Nov. 2024.

The relevant Wikipedia article, numerical digit, also covers this in the first 2 paragraphs. For the definition of a mathematical term you're better to consult Wikipedia than a general English dictionary.

Worth mentioning, if you're thinking etymologically: "bit" comes from "binary digit", and therefore explicitly encodes 2.  You might guess that the "d" in "digit" is somehow related to that in "decimal".   Bu tit's not - "digit" appears to be related to "dicere" meaning "to say".  Etymologically there's no reason for "digit" to be restricted to base 10.

I would also say, based solely on how it feels to me personally as a native speaker, that "digit" is only used for the symbols used in a positional numeral system, so I or X or V etc. as used in Roman numerals would not be called digits. But I don't have any source for that other than "it feels slightly wrong".

The word digit usually refers to one of the symbols 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, and 9 that are used to represent numbers in the commonly used base-10 or decimal system.
In the base-2, or binary, representation system, there are only two digits: 0 and 1. And these binary digits are more commonly referred to by the contraction bits.
Just as the decimal numeral (string of symbols) 102 means
1×100 + 0×10 + 2×1 = 102,
the same value is represented in binary as 1100110, since its analogous expression as a sum of powers of 2 is
1×64 + 1×32 + 0×16 + 0×8 + 1×4 + 1×2 + 0×1 = 1100110.
So when this number is expressed in decimal, the numeral has 3 digits, but when it is expressed in base-2, that binary numeral has 6 bits.
The digits of the base-16, or hexadecimal, system are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,and F.

In other words, yes, it can.

I would rather say that '0' and '1' are representations of bits, and not themselves bits, just as '0xFF' is not itself 'a byte'. Is this nit-picking?

I would say "yes, but only if the alternative base is specified", if it is not specified then for the modern world "digit" implies decimal.

The digits have the same value regardless of the base.  Decimal uses 10 digits.  Other bases use more or less.  It is only how digits combine to form larger numbers that depend on the base.

@MichaelHarvey I'd say it's at least a little nitpicky since "binary digit" is literally the etymology of "bit". But also I get the point you're making? I feel like the difference might be that "bit" can be either a value or a unit of measurement, but "byte" can only be a unit of measurement?

I think it is reasonable to say that 0 and 1 are the binary digits, and that 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 are the octal digits, and that as Oxford Reference says, the sixteen hexadecimal digits are usually represented by 0–9, A–F.

In everyday life, other bases don't come up, so “digit” means the symbols 0 through 9.
In typesetting, “digit” means the symbols used to represent numbers (more specifically, to represent positive integers). When typesetting English and other languages that use the same numerals, “digit” again means the symbols 0 through 9. When typesetting other languages with a different writing system, “digit” can refer to other symbols. Almost all languages that have a position-based numeral system use base 10, so there are usually 10 digits. For example, in Bengali writing, the “digits” are the symbols ০ through ৯ (Bengali numerals). But there are a few exceptions, for example Mayan numerals can be analyzed as having 20 digits, and Medefaidrin numerals definitely use 20 digits. Curiously, Unicode calls the symbols for the digits 10 to 19 “Medafaidrin number X”, not “Medafaidrin digit X”. Unicode reserves the word “digit” in a character name for symbols used in positional notation in base 10. But when discussing writing systems,  is the digit 10 in Medefaidrin.
In typesetting, “digit” is normally used only for symbols that are only intended to represent numbers in a positional numbering system. For example Roman numerals or cuneiform numerals are not usually called “digits”.
In mathematics, “digit” means a symbol used in the representation of positive integers. In a positional notation of integers, there are N symbols, where N is the base. Those N symbols are digits, regardless of how they're represented in writing. For example, in base 10, the digits are normally written 0 through 9. In base 2, the digits are normally written 0 and 1. In base 50, there are no conventional symbols, so you might write something like (11)(42)<sub>50</sub> to mean the number 11×50+42=592.
Many things related to computers use base 16, i.e. hexadecimal notation. When discussing hexadecimal notation, the word “digit” can either refer to the symbols 0 through 9 (the decimal digits), or the 16 positional symbols which includes the decimal digits as well as the letters A through F. By default, “digit” with no adjective tends to refer to the symbols 0 through 9. But the context can imply another meaning. For example (from the IBM InfoSphere Data Replication manual):

A hexadecimal digit is a digit or any of the letters A through F (upper case or lower case).

Or from the Arm Compiler armasm user guide:

hexadecimal-digits
Is a sequence of characters using only the digits 0 to 9 and the letters A to F or a to f.
(…)
base-n-digits
Is a sequence of characters using only the digits 0 to (n-1)


You can, it's not wrong, but I think "bits" or "binary digits" and "hex digits" or "hexadecimal digits" would be better (as in more understandable) in your examples.
Incidentally, the equivalent of '.' when the base is not 10 is "radix point", rather than "decimal point". For base-10 it could be either, of course.
